# Eclipse not able to access the internet but Java programs can

Tags: java, eclipse, networking

I am trying to get Eclipse to be able to access the internet so that I can install software, however eclipse can't access the internet. I wrote a simple Java program that accesses the internet and that was able to run fine. I am also able to browse the internet via Mozilla.

I am trying to access the eclipse marketplace and it is giving me the error:

```
Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace
Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Connection failed

This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection. Please check your internet connection and retry.
Cannot complete request to http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p: Unable to connect to repository http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p
Unable to connect to repository http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p
Connection timed out
Connection failed

This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection. Please check your internet connection and retry.
Connection timed out
```

I also tried using the internal web-browser and got the same issue.

OS: Linux Redhat

Eclipse: Neon or helios

Comment: @azurefrog, sorry - question is updated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a few posts about similar problems to this on stack such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794885/cant-access-eclipse-marketplace)
as there are many solutions to this problem and we are unsure what exactly your OS and firewall settings are the question is kind of broad but i do recommend trying the suggestions from that post:

> The service could be temporarily broken You could have a problem with
>   a firewall. These could be local or they could be implemented by your
>   ISPs. Your proxy HTTP settings (if you need one) could be incorrect.
>   This Answer explains how to adjust the Eclipse-internal proxy settings
>   ... if that is where the problem lies. It is possible that your access
>   may be blocked by over-active antivirus software. The service could
>   have blacklisted some net range and your hosts IP address is
>   "collateral damage".

and

> 1. GO TO
>
> Window-> Preferences -> General -> Network Connection.
>
> 2. Change the Settings
>
> Active Provider-> Manual-> and check---> HTTP, HTTPS and SOCKS

### could you provide details on whether your firewall is blocking any ports etc?

Edit

Theres another solution very similar to your problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140468/eclipse-frustration)

> It is related to IPv6 (dual stack) support in Java 7. The quickest
>   solution (if you dont need IPv6) would be to turn the IPv6 support
>   off, by appending this to vmargs argument of the  eclipse.ini file:
>
> -vmargs
>   -Xmx512m ...
>   -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true (end restart Eclipse).

This may be useful however the list remains exceedingly large on what could be causing the issue.

Comment: I saw, and tried, both of those sites answers. I have no blocked ports.

Comment: ah right, i made an edit to include another link with a fairly similar problem to you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140468/eclipse-frustration

Comment: that didn't seem to make any changes either.